# View specific stylesheets in Sinatra (by naming convention)

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I would like to have my Sinatra app include a view specific stylesheet in the layout.

Consider this simple app:

```
app_folder_root/
| my_app/
|   my_app.rb
| public/
|   css/
|     index.css
|     layout.css
| views/
|   index.haml
|   layout.haml
config.ru
```

config.ru:

```
require 'rubygems'
require './my_app/my_app'

map '/' do
  run MyApp
end
```

app.rb:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    haml :index
  end
end
```

I tried setting a variable in `my_app.rb` that sets the name of the view and tried to reference it in `layout.haml`, but that did not work (I probably wouldn't have went with this as a final solution to the problem since I felt this was a code smell, but was just trying different possibilities).

This is using Haml, but I am hoping that is irrelevant - thinking it should be the same for erb, etc.

In `layout.haml`, I would like to reference the view that will be rendered and include a view specific stylesheet by a naming convention. For example, if `index.haml` is going to render, I would like to include `css/index.css`. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by doing the following:

In `index.haml` (at the top) I created or appended an array named `views`:

```
- @views = Array.new unless defined? @views
- @views << 'index'
```

In `layout.haml` I reference `@views`:

```
%head
  - @views.each do |view|
    - haml_tag :link, {:rel => 'stylesheet', :type => 'text/css', :href => "css/#{view}.css"}
```

I am a little disappointed with having to check `@views` in the view to make sure it is defined before appending to it, but for now it is manageable.

EDIT: Solved the problem with having to check if `@views` is defined in each view. In `config.ru` add the following:

```
before do
  @views = Array.new
end
```

I can now remove this line from the views:

```
- @views = Array.new unless defined? @views
```